Autocomplete Textbox for Google with razor page
I'm designing a page where users can capture their address details. I'm looking for a way the user can select an address from a a list of options based on what was typed in the textbox.
I already have the google API keys and can do most of the things with the maps, but cannot get the Autocomplete to work,
I'm using Blazor with razor pages and C#
Any demo code or link would help.
Thank you.
